# Displaying a single number jQuery .each()

Tags: jquery, pagination, numbers, each, slide

Anyone know what I must change in this plugin that displaying a single number ( like "1/3" ) ?

http://slidesjs.com

I modified this line:

```
$('.' + option.paginationClass, elem).append('<li><a href="#'+ number +'">'+ (number+1) +'</a></li>');
```

and change to this:

```
$('.' + option.paginationClass, elem).append('<li><a href="#'+ number +'">'+ (number+1) +'/'+ total +'</a></li>');
```

and now shows me: "1/3 2/3 3/3".

Comment: In general "help me with this jQuery plugin" questions don't fare very well on StackOverflow. People don't mind helping you with code YOU write because you're making an effort. Helping you with code someone else wrote -- well go ask the person who wrote the plugin, or learn how to code.

Answer (score 0):

So... I believe you only want to display the current page number in the slideshow. So if you have a show of 5 slides, and you are on page 3, then you will only see "3/5". Correct?

So, answering this question, here is the **original** loop surrounding the code you posted above.

```
control.children().each(function(){
    $('.' + option.paginationClass, elem).append('<li><a href="#'+ number +'">'+ (number+1) +'</a></li>');
    number++;
});
```

However, to only display the current page we are on, we will need to add a conditional statement to display only the one page...

```
control.children().each(function(){
//Use a conditional statement to display only the current page
//Have jQuery find the slide which is not currently hidden from view
    if ($(this).css('display') == "block") {
        $('.' + option.paginationClass, elem).append('<li><a href="#'+ number +'">'+ (number+1) +'</a></li>');
        return false;
//If the element is not visible we still need to count up, in order to account for this page
    } else {
        number++;
    }
});
```

I'll admit, this code is not at all tested, but it *should* work. One thing I don't know is if it will automatically update as you scroll through the slides.

Hope this helps,
spryno724